# MySQL fulltext search over multiple columns

Tags: mysql, indexing, full-text-search, match-against

I've created a table with an full-text index over 2 columns:

```
CREATE TABLE players
(
    id int NOT NULL,
    first_name varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    last_name varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    team_id int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FULLTEXT INDEX full_text_pname (first_name, last_name),
    CONSTRAINT p_team_id FOREIGN KEY (team_id) REFERENCES teams (id)
);
```

Now I want to do a SQL query that recives first_name and last_name and selects the players with those values.

Instead of:

```
   SELECT first_name, last_name, team_id
   FROM players
   WHERE first_name = % s AND last_name = % s
```

How can i use match and against?

Comment: FTS does not take into account the column where the word is found, and the same for the words ordering in the value until the phrase search which searches in one column only.

Comment: So how can I search?

Comment: If you need in strict equiation then your variant is safe. Simply create composite index by these two columns. `.. , INDEX full_name (first_name, last_name), ..`.

Comment: I'm also not sure what's the point of using fulltext index or names! Most names will not  have that many words in them that a fulltext index would come handy.

Comment: I'm using a full-text index cause I need to (in my assignment). If I have a full-text index on column "a" and I'm querying: "WHERE a= 'bla'", am I using the full-text index? or is match against the only way to use the full-text index

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for the MATCH() function goes like this:

```
MATCH (col1,col2,...) AGAINST (expr [search_modifier])
```

[see documentation](https://database.guide/how-the-match-function-works-in-mysql/)

So the query would be something like this:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, team_id
FROM players
WHERE MATCH ( first_name ) AGAINST ("my_first_name" IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND
      MATCH ( last_name ) AGAINST ("my_last_name" IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Comment: No.  MATCH does not play well with AND.

Answer (score 0):

**Fastest** This

```
WHERE first_name = '...'
  AND last_name = '...'
```

with

```
INDEX(last_name, first_name)
```

would be faster than using `FULLTEXT`

**Medium speed** for doing an equality match on both columns, you need

```
WHERE MATCH(last, first)  -- the order must match the index
  AGAINST('+James +Rick IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

with

```
FULLEXT(last, first)
```

And it has various issues.  It matches Rick, James as well as James, Rick.  Probably it would match Jame, Ricks since it treats words as English and plays with endings.  Etc.

**Slowest** This does *not* run fast:

```
WHERE MATCH ...
  AND MATCH ...
```